# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't recognize Super-key as part of shortcuts on Fedora 22 (Gnome 3.16)

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, fedora, gnome, intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA doesn't recognize the Super_L/Meta-key as part of a shortcut or individually, while Super_R is strangely recognized as "Windows"-key. Both as part of existing shortcuts (no recognition, so Meta+Strg+J is the same as Strg+J) or when trying to use it in the shortcut search (just pressing it opens the Gnome shell-menu, but otherwise same behaviora s above)

This seems to be a pure Intellij Idea problem, because shortcuts involving either Super_L or Super_R are properly detected and the keys are also labeled properly (e.g. not as "Windows"-key).

This should also not be part of [this problem](https://superuser.com/questions/415675/gnome-shell-3-4-and-a-super-key-related-shortcut), because the [related bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=659899#c49) got fixed.

I installed Intellij Idea 14.1.4 via [Fedy](https://github.com/satya164/fedy)

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem with CLion. Considering the IDEs use the same base source a fix here should apply for IntelliJ as well.

Opened issue at:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-4246

Comment: Following links from there, it looks like they added a workaround: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144702#comment=27-1491339 add `keymap.windows.as.meta=true` to editor's Custom Properties.

Comment: @keturn That solution solved the problem for me. I know it is workaround but still helpful. Thanks.